# SQL Incorrect total while combining equations

Tags: sql-server, variables, aggregate-functions

For a report I am creating I need to take two separate expressions and combine them to get one solution.

The first expression I need is the `Total Sales` which is calculated by

```
Sum([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) AS [Total Sales]
```

The second expression I need is the `Total Cost`which is calculated by

```
 Max(CAST ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight AS DECIMAL (18,2))) AS [Cost]
```

Both of those statements work because they are used for other columns in the query and display properly.

In order to find out the Total Profit I tried to combine the two using `SUM, AVG, MAX and by trying to make it an expression but that results in an error.` I believe the code below has the right idea, it is just missing some important parts. Perhaps an `OVER()` statement:

```
CAST (([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [Profit]
```

The problem I have is that it is calculating the profit for each row but I only want the total profit. Which would make it an aggregate function I believe. Or is there a way to store the other two expressions as variables and use those?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Full code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;

SELECT 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , CAST (@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [Shrink]
   , Max(CAST ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight AS DECIMAL (18,2))) AS [Cost]
   , Max(CAST (([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS [Profit]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND [ARC].CustomerKey IN (124) ) 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , [ARC].CustomerKey
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) 
   , CAST (@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
   , Max(CAST ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight AS DECIMAL (18,2))) 
   , Max(CAST (([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
```

Temp Table

so I would create an expression similar to

```
SELECT Sum([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) as Total Sales 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey) INNER JOIN AR_Customers [ARC] ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey) INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey) LEFT OUTER JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
GROUP BY unitcost
```

Comment: Are you trying to get Total Profit for all products combined? Meaning each row shows the same value? In that case, you could use a nested `(Select SUM( [your formula] ) from [your table]) as Total Profit`

Comment: @Samcd yes, not necessarily each row shows the same value because I would have it casted as a heading but yes, there should only be one value for the Total Profit and it should be the same for the whole report. Does that make sense?

Comment: why are you using MAX?

Comment: @Samcd for the second expression? Because that is the only way I could get it to work without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;
```

Put all your raw data into a temp table like this:

```
    SELECT 
         CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
       , [PC].ProductCode
       , [PC].Description1
       , IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt AS [Boxes]
       , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
       , IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk AS [Weight]
       , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
       , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
       , [DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost] AS [Total Sales]
       , ([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt]) AS [Avg. Box Weight] --not sure about this one
       , [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight AS [Yield]
       , CAST([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [Shrink]
       , CAST ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight AS DECIMAL (18,2)) AS [Cost]
       , CAST (([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [Profit]
  INTO #TempTable
     FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
        INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
         ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
        INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
         ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
        INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
         ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
         ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
     WHERE 
        (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
    AND ((1=1)  AND [ARC].CustomerKey IN (124) )
```

then either set up your aggregates as variables to be used in a `select` statement:

```
DECLARE @TotalSales decimal(19,8) = (SELECT Sum([Total Sales]) FROM #TempTable
DECLARE @TotalProfit decimal(19,8) = (SELECT SUM([Profit]) FROM #TempTable
DECLARE @TotalCost decimal(19,8) = (SELECT SUM([Cost]) FROM #TempTable
```

or

```
SELECT
[FieldNames]
[Aggregates]
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY [Any field not included in the aggregates]
```

Comment: hmm that formats the value properly but the number is way way way off. That may be an error on my side though.

Comment: the problem with declaring the variables that way is that I can't use a WHERE statement in the SETS because the WHERE varies based on user input.

Comment: Would you be able to put the basic data (without aggregates) into a temp table, and then perform your calculations from there?

Comment: I do not believe so because the program my company uses does not allow me to add tables. All the tables are already prebuilt.

Comment: you don't need permissions to create temp tables. `SELECT [...] INTO #tempTableName FROM [...]`. The table will be deleted when the session is closed

Comment: would I do something similar to what I posted in the question